# Need Help in resampling the dataset

Tags: data-science, interpolation, sampling, resampling, downsampling

I have a data set of dow_jones_index. I was asked to perform following activities:

1. downsample the data filtered in the above step day wise and perform
   interpolation to forward fill the first two 'Nan' values.
2. return the first 10 samples of downsampled data to variable
   'downsample'

I've written following lines of codes:

```
import pandas as pd
dataFrame = pd.read_csv('dow_jones_index.data',parse_dates=["date"], index_col="date")
dataFrame.head()
closeTS = dataFrame[(dataFrame.stock == 'AA')].close.str.replace('$',' ').astype(float)
down = closeTS.resample('D')
downsample = down.interpolate(method='linear',limit=None,limit_direction='forward').head(10)
from test_ts_resample_day import values
values.save_ans1(downsample)
```

But it is not satisfying all the test cases. Please help me to improve the code.

Answer (score 0):

downsample = closeTS.resample('D', fill_method='ffill', limit=2).head(10)